# "Prissy dresser" meaning

Tags: meaning

From the movie *The Life of David Gale* -  "Socrates was ugly, Plato was fat, and, um, and Aristotle was a prissy dresser!"

What does the term "prissy dresser" actually mean?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the word with which you are having trouble is ***prissy***.

It is a word of late-nineteenth century coinage, of US origin, defined by the OED as

*Precise and over-particular; (affectedly) prim or prudish, esp. in a manner considered feminine or effeminate.*